# C# .NET Compact Framework, custom UserControl, focus issue

Tags: .net, windows-mobile, user-controls, coldfusion

I have a custom UserControl (a label and a textbox).

My problem is I need to handle the key down, key up events to navigate between controls in the form ([.NET Compact Framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Compact_Framework) textbox, combobox, etc). With the controls provided by the .NET Compact Framework framework it works, but when I reach a usercontrol written by me, that control don`t get focus (the textbox inside get the focus) so from this usercontrol I cannot navigate because in the panel I don't have any control of who have focus.

A little mock up :
Form->Panel->controls -> on keydown event (using KeyPreview) with a foreach I check what control have focus on the panel and pass to the next control with SelectNextControl, but no one have focus  because the usercontrol don`t got focus...

I tried to handle the textbox gotFocus event and put focus to the user control, but I got an infinite loop..

Does somebody have any idea what can I do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We've done the exact same thing on Compact Framework, adding a global focus manager that supports navigating between controls using keyboard input.

Basically, what you need to do is to recurse down the tree of controls until you find a control that has focus. It's not terribly efficient, but as long as you only do it once per key event, it shouldn't be an issue.

**Edit:** Added the code for our recursive focus finding function:

```
public static Control FindFocusedControl(Control container)
{
    foreach (Control childControl in container.Controls) {
        if (childControl.Focused) {
            return childControl;
        }
    }

    foreach (Control childControl in container.Controls) {
        Control maybeFocusedControl = FindFocusedControl(childControl);
        if (maybeFocusedControl != null) {
            return maybeFocusedControl;
        }
    }

    return null; // Couldn't find any, darn!
}
```

Comment: Thank you! (need more five char from the system to let to add this comment)

Comment: Sweet Answer.  This is one of the few reliable ways to get the focus.

Comment: @thephpdeveloper - It will basically make the difference between a Breadth First Search and a Depth First Search, our assumption was the the first approach would terminate quicker most of the time.

Comment: ah yes i see it now. I have something against double iterations, so forgive me

Answer (score 0):

It's normal that your panel doesn't receive any focus. What you can try is to look if any children of your usercontrol contains the focus. Something like this:

```
bool ContainsFocus(Control lookAtMe) {
 if (lookAtMe.Focused) return true;
 else {
     foreach (Control c in lookAtMe.Controls) {
         if (c.Focused) return true;
     }
 }
 return false;
}
```

You could also traverse them recursively if that's needed, but I don't think that's one of your requirements here.