# Know who got the focus in a Lost Focus event

Tags: c#, compact-framework, focus

Is it possible to know who got the focus in a lost focus event?

Compact Framework does not have an `ActiveControl`, so I don't know how to tell who got the focus.

Comment: You've stated in the below answer comments you want to use the LostFocus event to show a message based on the control that's in focus. Why not just use the GotFocus event of the control in question instead?

Comment: @GenericTypeTea - Good point.  More than showing a message, I needed to also do some processing on the value of the control that is being left.  Could be done in the GotFocus, but it would be a bit awkward.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the solution that ended up working:

```
public System.Windows.Forms.Control FindFocusedControl()
{
    return FindFocusedControl(this);
}

public static System.Windows.Forms.Control FindFocusedControl(System.Windows.Forms.Control container)
{
    foreach (System.Windows.Forms.Control childControl in container.Controls)
    {
        if (childControl.Focused)
        {
            return childControl;
        }
    }

    foreach (System.Windows.Forms.Control childControl in container.Controls)
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.Control maybeFocusedControl = FindFocusedControl(childControl);
        if (maybeFocusedControl != null)
        {
            return maybeFocusedControl;
        }
    }

    return null; // Couldn't find any, darn!
}
```

Answer (score 2):

One option would be to interop the GetFocus API

```
[DllImport("coredll.dll, EntryPoint="GetFocus")]
public extern static IntPtr GetFocus();
```

This will give you the handle to the window that currently has input focus, you can then recursively iterate the control tree to find the control with that handle.

Comment: Keep in mind that calling GetFocus in the LostFocus event will yield the control losing focus, so while GetFocus will give you the current control, you have to have some event to know when to call it.

Comment: @ctacke - wow, that sounds... complicated.  So to sum up, if I call GetFocus at the wrong time (like in the LostFocus event) it will actually change the current focus rather than just tell me what control has focus?

Answer (score 1):

No. first comes the LostFocus-event of one control then comes the GotFocus-event of the next control. as long as you can not figure out which control the user uses in the next moment, it is not possible.
whereas if the compact framework control does have a TabIndex-property it could be predicted only if the user uses the tab-key.

Edit:
OK You posted the solution and it works fine I must admit: the simple "No" is wrong
+1

Comment: So I am confused... This doc says that GotFocus goes before LostFocus.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.gotfocus.aspx But I am seeing LostFocus go first (as you said).

Comment: the document is of course right, but it lacks the information which control is actually meant. therefore read carefuly what I have written: LostFocus of the one control comes before the GotFocus of the _NEXT_ control. the MSDN just says GotFocus comes before LostFocus of the *same* control. You talk about "seeing" so I assume you made a small example, where you e.g. store the occurence of the Lost- and Gotfocus events of different controls in a ListBox.

Comment: Ah... I see now.  Well, that makes sense, but I am still no closer to a solution to my problem.

Comment: maybe describe what you really want to do with it, maybe there is another better solution?

Comment: In my lost focus method, I wanted to show a message (or not) based on the control that got the focus.

Comment: I'd implement an IMessageFilter and just look for teh low-level messages based on the control handles you're interested in there.  That's the simplest, least kludgey way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Using the corell.dll looks like a good idea.

Another possible way is to create GotFocus event handlers for all the controls on your form  Then create a class level variable that updates with the name of the control that has the current focus.

Comment: I tried that (see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2829321/find-the-focused-control-in-a-form-in-netcf)  It did not work (\because of the LostFocus going before the GotFocus (as indidcated by Oops)

Answer (score 1):

This is a shorter code for the Vaccano's answer, using Linq

```
private static Control FindFocusedControl(Control container)
{
    foreach (Control childControl in container.Controls.Cast<Control>().Where(childControl => childControl.Focused)) return childControl;
    return (from Control childControl in container.Controls select FindFocusedControl(childControl)).FirstOrDefault(maybeFocusedControl => maybeFocusedControl != null);
}
```

Exactly the same (in high-level, abstraction).