# How to get the form active control?

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-mobile, windows-ce

Is there a way to get the form active control?

I was checking in the help for the `"Support.GetActiveControl"` method but it isn't supported :) for the **Compact Framework**.

I suppose that I can track the focus by adding a custom `GotFocus` event handler to all the form controls, but I'm looking for a more generic way that can be implemented for any form.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Know who got the focus in a Lost Focus event](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2899338/know-who-got-the-focus-in-a-lost-focus-event)

Answer (score 8):

This example displays the name of the currently selected Windows Forms control in a Label control.

```
private void DisplayNameOfActiveControl()
{
    label1.Text = this.ActiveControl.Name;
}
```

Comment: -1: As per the question `ActiveControl` does not exist in Compact Framework.

Comment: Furthermore, if you have, for example, a textbox in a splitcontainer, it will return splitcontainer rather than textbox

Answer (score 2):

You can iterate over all the controls in the form and check which one is focused.

Example: [Getting ActiveControl in Compact Framework](http://softwarex-nz.blogspot.com/2006/08/getting-activecontrol-in-compact.html)