# How to acces to a textBox by press Key up?

Tags: c#, winforms

so I works in a **c#** project (winforms), so I have a lot of textboxes in my project and I want when I press key <kbd>up</kbd>, a specific textbox let say `textbox1` increment his value, I already use the event `OnKeyUp` but the problem it I have a lot of textboxes so I have to click into this `TextBox1` to start the operation, so please if someone have any idea i will be very appreciate.

this is my code:

```
//Action speed up
private void TxBoxKeyUp_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    TxBoxKeyUp.Text = (speed+=5).ToString();
    LbSpeed.Text = TxBoxKeyUp.Text;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to handle the KeyUp event for every control on your form then you could set the [Form.KeyPreview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.keypreview.aspx) property to True. 
Then add a KeyUp event handler for your form  and in this event update the contents of your textbox

```
private void Form1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    TxBoxKeyUp.Text = (speed+=5).ToString();
    LbSpeed.Text = TxBoxKeyUp.Text;
}
```

This works fine if your intent is to catch every KeyUp whatever control is the focused control at the time the event fires. If you need to get keyups only when the control focused is a TextBox then the solution is more complex. You need a [method like the one explained in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2899338/know-who-got-the-focus-in-a-lost-focus-event) to get the current focused control and then check if it is a textbox.

Answer (score 0):

You can define your textboxes as a array and then use delegate.

lets assume you have a single keyup event **TxBoxKeyUp_KeyUp** and a array of textboxes **txtarr**

```
foreach (TextBox txt in txtarr)
    txt.KeyUp += new KeyEventHandler(TxBoxKeyUp_KeyUp);
```

So you can handle all the textboxes keyup event with a single function.