# Get the focused component in Windows Forms

Tags: c#, winforms, compact-framework, .net-2.0, windows-ce

I need to get the component that has the focus in the moment with Windows Forms and .NET Framework 2.0 - C# or VisualBasic

I have an event that, in some moment, receive a text and it needs to put this text inside of a `TextBox` component. But it isn't just a component. Must be the focused component. My situation is: I'm working with low level applications and hardware communication that gets a string from a hardware reader and I must append this text to the focused `TextBox`.

```
_device = new Device(Device.AvailableDevices[0].DeviceName);
_leitor = new Reader(_device);
_leitorDados = new ReaderData(ReaderDataTypes.Text, ReaderDataLengths.MaximumLabel);
_leitor.Actions.Enable();
_leitor.Actions.Read(_leitorDados);
_leitor.StatusNotify += delegate
{
    if (_leitorDados.Text == String.Empty) return;
    MessageBox.Show(_leitorDados.Text);
    _leitorDados = new ReaderData(ReaderDataTypes.Text, ReaderDataLengths.MaximumLabel);
    _leitor.Actions.Read(_leitorDados);
};
```

My text is found in `_leitorDados.Text` and, when I receive the event, I need to do

`focusedControl.Text = _leitorDados.Text;`

But I'm using a very limited version of .NET Framework, the 2.0 and I have not so many possibilities to do it.
Thanks in advance.

- This question differs of the others in Stack Overflow because it is about a determinated version of .NET Framework, that hasn't the resources I'd need to perform this.
- There is no `this.ActiveControl` in .NET Framework 2.0. together with Win-CE

[image]

Comment: There is not .net 2.5 I suppose. Also tag your questions with which version of framework and Windows CE

Comment: Yeah. I messed up. is .NET 2.0. I Checked it in properties now. Thank you.

Comment: As per [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.containercontrol.activecontrol%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) it is supported. Supported platform has  Windows CE

Comment: Let me take a screenshot...

Comment: You should note that this is Compact Framework, look here for answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2905841/351383

Comment: possible duplicate of [Know who got the focus in a Lost Focus event](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2899338/know-who-got-the-focus-in-a-lost-focus-event)

Comment: I see now. It is really duplicate of that question I didn't find before. Please, somebody, tag it as duplicate.

Comment: I vote for Antonio Bakula (linq is not supported by .Net 2): public static System.Windows.Forms.Control FindFocusedControl(System.Windows.Forms.Control container)
{
    foreach (System.Windows.Forms.Control childControl in container.Controls)
    {
        if (childControl.Focused)
        {
            return childControl;
        }
    }...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do this using a recursive approach. Try this:

```
public static Control FindFocusedComponent(Control control)
{
    foreach (Control child in control.Controls)
    {
        if (child.Focused)
        {
            return child;
        }
    }

    foreach (Control child in control.Controls)
    {
        Control focused = FindFocusedComponent(child);

        if (focused != null)
        {
            return focused;
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```